# html5 placeholders align

Tags: html

I have text inputs in `rtl` page (hebrew) with fields for email and phone numbers. now these fields are written `ltr`. so, their placeholders are shown on left side of input field, while all others are on the right side (remember, `rtl`). Is there as way to change the align of placeholder text?

Answer (score 0):

I am quite unsure how they respond to positioning attributes, but at least I've been successful in changing font\color etc via these two selectors:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder { }
input:-moz-placeholder { }
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about font\color changing, but positioning is not a part of it :(